Prettier included in package.json but not available in default formatter selection list
In an Angular project that I'm developing in Visual Studio Code, I have the following in package.json:
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.1.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^17.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.1.1",
    "@angular/localize": "^17.1.1",
    "@types/file-saver-es": "^2.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.1",
    "@types/node": "^18.11.18",
    "copy-modules-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-marbles": "^0.9.2",
    "karma": "~6.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "prettier": "3.2.5",
    "typescript": "~5.3.3",
    "webpack": "^5.88.2"
  },
  "prettier": {
    "bracketSameLine": true,
    "printWidth": 120,
    "singleQuote": true,
    "trailingComma": "es5",
    "endOfLine": "auto"
  }

This is on a laptop I've had for about six weeks. Prettier formatting on save worked fine on my last laptop and it's working for my colleagues, but when I try to select it as my default formatter on this laptop, it isn't available in the Default Formatter list:
.
The list continues but when I scroll, Prettier still isn't an option. What am I missing?

Is the extension installed?

No. I used to have it on my old laptop, then I learned that the extension isn't maintained frequently and was stuck on an old version of Prettier, which wasn't handling the newer Angular @for, @if, etc. constructs. So we switched to the NPM version and I thought I'd removed the extension from the old laptop. Maybe I didn't?

I installed the Extension and now it works. I guess I was misremembering--now I think it's that if  an NPM package is installed, the extension will use that. Otherwise, it will fall back on the version it comes with, which is old. Thanks for the push in that direction.

See my comments in response to @jonrsharpe, above. Yeah, I hadn't installed the extension. I'd misremembered the connection between the extension and any NPM package that might be installed with the application.
